# How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?

Tags: powershell, wix, windows-installer, installation, uninstallation

I need to find the **product GUID** for an **installed MSI file** in order to perform maintenance such as **`patching`**, **`uninstall`** ([**how-to uninstall**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)) and also for **`auditing purposes`**.

Comment: The absolute simplest and quickest way: https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/MsiRetrieveProductCode.vbs (save and run from desktop - outputs msiinfo.csv).

Answer (score 230, accepted):

> For **upgrade code** retrieval:
> **[How can I find the Upgrade Code for an installed MSI file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637094/how-can-i-find-the-upgrade-code-for-an-installed-msi-file/46637095#46637095)** ([or use the html table export script](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/MsiHtmlReport-Mini-V4.vbs) - shown below in section 2)

---

### Short Version

The information below has grown considerably over time and may have become a little too elaborate. **How to get product codes quickly?** (four approaches):

### 1 - `Use the Powershell "one-liner"`

*Scroll down for screenshot and step-by-step*. Disclaimer also below - minor or moderate risks depending on who you ask. Works OK for me. Any **self-repair** triggered by this option should generally be possible to cancel. The **package integrity checks** triggered does add some event log "noise" though. **Note**! `IdentifyingNumber` **is** the `ProductCode` (WMI peculiarity).

```ps
get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Sort-Object -Property Name |Format-Table IdentifyingNumber, Name, LocalPackage -AutoSize
```

**Quick start of Powershell**: hold <kbd>Windows key</kbd>, tap <kbd>R</kbd>, type in "powershell" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

***UPDATE***: As commented by Alexis Coles, you can skip WMI and go via COM (faster):

```ps
$Installer = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer; $InstallerProducts = $Installer.ProductsEx("", "", 7); $InstalledProducts = ForEach($Product in $InstallerProducts){[PSCustomObject]@{ProductCode = $Product.ProductCode(); LocalPackage = $Product.InstallProperty("LocalPackage"); VersionString = $Product.InstallProperty("VersionString"); ProductPath = $Product.InstallProperty("ProductName")}} $InstalledProducts
```

[If you want the upgrade code, maybe use the html export instead](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/MsiHtmlReport-Mini-V4.vbs) (section 2 below)

### 2 - `Use VBScript` ([script on github.com](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/MsiRetrieveProductCode.vbs) - [html export version](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/MsiHtmlReport-Mini-V4.vbs))

Described below under "**Alternative Tools" (section 3)**. This option may be **safer** than Powershell for reasons explained in detail below. In essence it is (much) **faster** and not capable of triggering MSI self-repair since it does not go through WMI (it accesses the [MSI COM API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367810(v=vs.85).aspx) directly - at blistering speed). *However, it is more involved than the Powershell option* (several lines of code).

***Heads Up***: The html version also gets the upgrade code. It can trigger both self-repair and excessive logging. See warnings embedded in the [script itself](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/MsiHtmlReport-Mini-V4.vbs). Usually it runs without issues, but takes a while to complete.

[image: HTML package estate script output]

### 3 - `Registry Lookup`

Some swear by looking things up in the registry. Not my recommended approach - I like going through proper APIs (or in other words: OS function calls). There are always weird exceptions accounted for only by the internals of the API-implementation:

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

### 4 - `Original MSI File / WiX Source`

You can find the [`Product Code`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the [`Property table`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of any MSI file (and any other property as well). However, the GUID could conceivably (rarely) be overridden by a transform applied at install time and hence not match the GUID the product is registered under (approach 1 and 2 above will report the real product code - that is registered with Windows - in such rare scenarios).

**You need a tool to view MSI files**. See towards the bottom of the following answer for a list of free tools you can download (or see quick option below): [How can I compare the content of two (or more) MSI files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546)

**UPDATE**: You can download [SuperOrca](http://www.pantaray.com/msi_super_orca.html) - the tool is good enough to get the job done - install, open MSI and go straight to the [Property table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and find the `ProductCode` row (please run the download through a malware check - you can use [virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) to do so - online scan utilizing dozens of anti-virus and malware suites to scan what you upload).

> **Orca** is Microsoft's own tool, it is installed with **Visual Studio** and
> the **Windows SDK**. Try searching for **`Orca-x86_en-us.msi`** - under
> **`Program Files (x86)`** and install the MSI if found.
>
> - ***Current path***: **`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86`**
> - Change version numbers as required towards the end of the path - obviously

---

And below you will find the original answer which "organically grew" into a lot of detail.

Maybe see "**Uninstall MSI Packages**" section below if this is the task you need to perform.

---

### Retrieve Product Codes

> **UPDATE**: If you also need the **upgrade code**, check this answer:
> **[How can I find the Upgrade Code for an installed MSI file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637094/how-can-i-find-the-upgrade-code-for-an-installed-msi-file/46637095#46637095)** (retrieves associated product codes, upgrade codes & product names in
> a table output - similar to the one below).
>
> - **Can't use PowerShell?** See "Alternative Tools" section below.
> - **Looking to uninstall?** See "Uninstall MSI packages" section below.

Fire up **Powershell** (*hold down the Windows key, tap R, release the Windows key, type in "powershell" and press OK*) and run the command below to get a list of installed MSI package **product codes** along with the **local cache package path** and the **product name** (maximize the PowerShell window to avoid truncated names).

Before running this command line, please read the disclaimer below (nothing dangerous, just some potential nuisances). Section 3 under "Alternative Tools" shows an alternative non-WMI way to get the same information using VBScript. If you are trying to uninstall a package there is a section below with some sample msiexec.exe command lines:

```ps
get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table IdentifyingNumber, Name, LocalPackage -AutoSize
```

The **output** should be similar to this:

[image]

***Note!** For some strange reason the **"ProductCode"** is referred to as **"IdentifyingNumber"** in WMI*. So in other words - in the picture above the IdentifyingNumber **is** the ProductCode.

If you need to **run this query remotely against lots of remote computer**, see "*Retrieve Product Codes From A Remote Computer*" section below.

> **DISCLAIMER** (important, please read before running the command!): Due to strange Microsoft design, any WMI call to `Win32_Product`
> (like the PowerShell command below) will trigger a **validation of the
> package estate**. Besides being **quite slow**, this can in rare cases
> trigger an MSI self-repair. This can be a small package or something
> huge - like Visual Studio. In most cases this does not happen - but
> there is a risk. *Don't run this command right before an important
> meeting - it is not ever dangerous (it is read-only), but it might
> lead to a long repair in very rare cases* (I think you can cancel the
> self-repair as well - unless actively prevented by the package in question, but it will restart if you call Win32_Product
> again and this will persist until you let the self-repair finish - sometimes it might continue even if you do let it finish: [How can I determine what causes repeated Windows Installer self-repair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263#6066263)).
>
> And just for the record: [some people report their event logs filling up with MsiInstaller EventID 1035 entries](https://serverfault.com/questions/43067/what-could-be-causing-msiinstaller-to-continuously-reconfigure-applicationseven) (see code chief's answer) - apparently caused by WMI queries to  the Win32_Product class (personally I have never seen this). This is **not** directly related to the Powershell command suggested above, it is in context of general use of the WIM class Win32_Product.

You can also get the output in list form (instead of table):

```ps
get-wmiobject -class Win32_Product
```

In this case the output is similar to this:

[image]

---

### Retrieve Product Codes From A Remote Computer

In theory you should just be able to specify a remote computer name as part of the command itself. Here is the same command as above set up to run on the machine "RemoteMachine" (`-ComputerName RemoteMachine` section added):

```
get-wmiobject Win32_Product -ComputerName RemoteMachine | Format-Table IdentifyingNumber, Name, LocalPackage -AutoSize
```

This might work if you are running with domain admin rights on a proper domain. In a workgroup environment (small office / home network), you probably have to add user credentials directly to the WMI calls to make it work.

Additionally, remote connections in WMI are affected by (at least) the **Windows Firewall**, **DCOM settings**, and **User Account Control (UAC)** (plus any additional non-Microsoft factors - for instance **real firewalls**, **third party software firewalls**, **security software of various kinds**, etc...). Whether it will work or not depends on your exact setup.

- [Setting up a Remote WMI Connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa822854(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Connecting to WMI Remotely with PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309377(v=vs.85).aspx)

**UPDATE**: An extensive section on remote WMI running can be found in this answer: [How can I find the Upgrade Code for an installed MSI file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637094/how-can-i-find-the-upgrade-code-for-an-installed-msi-file/46637095#46637095). It appears a firewall rule and suppression of the UAC prompt via a registry tweak can make things work in a workgroup network environment. Not recommended changes security-wise, but it worked for me.

---

### Alternative Tools

**PowerShell** requires the **.NET framework** to be installed (currently in version 3.5.1 it seems? October, 2017). The actual PowerShell application itself **can also be missing** from the machine even if .NET is installed. Finally I believe PowerShell can be **disabled or locked** by various system policies and privileges.

If this is the case, you can try a few other ways to retrieve product codes. My preferred alternative is **VBScript** - it is fast and flexible (but can also be locked on certain machines, and scripting is always a little more involved than using tools).

1. Let's start with a **built-in Windows WMI tool**: `wbemtest.exe`.

- Launch `wbemtest.exe` (*Hold down the Windows key, tap R, release the Windows key, type in "wbemtest.exe" and press OK*).
- Click **connect** and then **OK** (namespace defaults to root\cimv2), and click "**connect**" again.
- Click "**Query**" and type in this **WQL command** (SQL flavor): `SELECT IdentifyingNumber,Name,Version FROM Win32_Product` and click "Use" (or equivalent - the tool will be localized).
- Sample output screenshot (truncated). Not the nicest formatting, but you can get the data you need. **IdentifyingNumber is the MSI product code**:

[image: wbemtest.exe]

2. Next, you can try a custom, more full featured WMI tool such as `WMIExplorer.exe`

- This is not included in Windows. It is a very good tool, however. Recommended.
- Check it out at: https://github.com/vinaypamnani/wmie2/releases
- Launch the tool, click Connect, double click ROOT\CIMV2
- From the "**Query tab**", type in the following query `SELECT IdentifyingNumber,Name,Version FROM Win32_Product` and press Execute.
- Screenshot skipped, the application requires too much screen real estate.

3. Finally you can try a **VBScript** to access information via **the MSI automation interface** (core feature of Windows - it is **unrelated to WMI**).

- Copy the below script and paste into a *.vbs file on your desktop, and try to run it by double clicking. Your desktop must be writable for you, or you can use any other writable location.
- This is not a great VBScript. **Terseness has been preferred** over error handling and completeness, but it should do the job with minimum complexity.
- The output file is created in the folder where you run the script from (**folder must be writable**). The output file is called `msiinfo.csv`.
- Double click the file to open in a spreadsheet application, select comma as delimiter on import - OR - just open the file in Notepad or any text viewer.
- Opening in a spreadsheet will allow advanced sorting features.
- This script can easily be adapted to show [a significant amount of further details about the MSI installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370865(v=vs.85).aspx). A demonstration of this can be found here: [how to find out which products are installed - newer product are already installed MSI windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963089/how-to-find-out-which-products-are-installed-newer-product-are-already-install/28971679#28971679).

```vb
' Retrieve all ProductCodes (with ProductName and ProductVersion)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set output = fso.CreateTextFile("msiinfo.csv", True, True)
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")

On Error Resume Next ' we ignore all errors

For Each product In installer.ProductsEx("", "", 7)
   productcode = product.ProductCode
   name = product.InstallProperty("ProductName")
   version=product.InstallProperty("VersionString")
   output.writeline (productcode & ", " & name & ", " & version)
Next

output.Close
```

> I can't think of any further general purpose options to retrieve product codes at the moment, please add if you know of any. **Just edit inline** rather than adding too many comments please.
>
> You can certainly access this information from within your application
> by calling [the MSI automation interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367810(v=vs.85).aspx) (COM based) OR the [C++
> MSI installer functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369426(v=vs.85).aspx) (Win32 API). Or even use WMI queries from within your application like you do in the samples above using `PowerShell`, `wbemtest.exe` or `WMIExplorer.exe`.

---

### Uninstall MSI Packages

If what you want to do is to **uninstall the MSI package** you found the product code for, you can do this as follows using an **elevated command prompt** (search for **cmd.exe**, right click and **run as admin**):

**Option 1**: ***Basic, interactive uninstall without logging*** (quick and easy):

```
msiexec.exe /x {00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000C}
```

Quick Parameter Explanation:

```
/X = run uninstall sequence
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000C} = product code for product to uninstall
```

You can also enable (verbose) logging and run in silent mode if you want to, leading us to option 2:

**Option 2**: ***Silent uninstall with verbose logging*** (better for batch files):

```
msiexec.exe /x {00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000C} /QN /L*V "C:\My.log" REBOOT=ReallySuppress
```

Quick Parameter Explanation:

```
/X = run uninstall sequence
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000C} = product code for product to uninstall
/QN = run completely silently
/L*V "C:\My.log"= verbose logging at specified path
REBOOT=ReallySuppress = avoid unexpected, sudden reboot
```

There is a **comprehensive reference for MSI uninstall** here (various different ways to uninstall MSI packages): [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933). There is a plethora of different ways to uninstall.

*If you are writing a batch file, please have a look at section 3 in the above, linked answer for a few common and standard uninstall command line variants.*

And a quick link to [**msiexec.exe (command line options)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx) (overview of the command line for msiexec.exe from MSDN). And [**the Technet version**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490936.aspx) as well.

---

### Retrieving other MSI Properties / Information (f.ex Upgrade Code)

> **UPDATE**: please find [**a new answer on how to find the upgrade code for installed packages**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637094/how-can-i-find-the-upgrade-code-for-an-installed-msi-file/46637095#46637095) instead of manually looking up the code in MSI files. For
> installed packages this is much more reliable. If the package is not
> installed, you still need to look in the MSI file (or the source file
> used to compile the MSI) to find the upgrade code. Leaving in older section below:

If you want to get the **UpgradeCode** or **other MSI properties**, you can open the cached installation MSI for the product from the location specified by "**LocalPackage**" in the image show above (something like: `C:\WINDOWS\Installer\50c080ae.msi` - it is a hex file name, unique on each system). Then you look in the "**Property table**" for UpgradeCode (it is possible for the UpgradeCode to be redefined in a transform - to be sure you get the right value you need to retrieve the code programatically from the system - I will provide a script for this shortly. However, **the UpgradeCode found in the cached MSI is generally correct**).

To open the cached MSI files, use **[Orca](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx)** or another packaging tool. Here is a discussion of different tools (any of them will do): [What installation product to use? InstallShield, WiX, Wise, Advanced Installer, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941). If you don't have such a tool installed, your fastest bet might be to try [Super Orca](http://www.pantaray.com/msi_super_orca.html) (it is simple to use, but not extensively tested by me).

**UPDATE**: here is a new answer with information on various free products you can use to view MSI files: [How can I compare the content of two (or more) MSI files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546)

**If you have Visual Studio installed**, try searching for `Orca-x86_en-us.msi` - under `Program Files (x86)` - and install it (this is Microsoft's own, official MSI viewer and editor). Then find Orca in the start menu. Go time in no time :-). Technically Orca is installed as part of Windows SDK (not Visual Studio), but Windows SDK is bundled with the Visual Studio install. **If you don't have Visual Studio installed**, perhaps you know someone who does? Just have them search for this MSI and send you (it is a tiny half mb file) - should take them seconds. **UPDATE**: you need several CAB files as well as the MSI - these are found in the same folder where the MSI is found. If not, you can always download the [Windows SDK](https://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2ysel8NHWAhUFJJoKHYT_BtAQFgg2MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownload%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fid%3D8279&usg=AOvVaw3mrsyO8I-U3TARNBi01WHG) (it is free, but it is big - and everything you install will slow down your PC). I am not sure which part of the SDK installs the Orca MSI. If you do, please just edit and add details here.

---

- Here is a more comprehensive article on the issue of MSI uninstall:  [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)
- Here is a similar article with **a few further options** for retrieving MSI information using the registry or the cached msi: **[Find GUID From MSI File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251034/find-guid-from-msi-file?)**

---

Similar topics (for reference and easy access - I should clean this list up):

- [How to find the UpgradeCode and ProductCode of an installed application in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063129/how-to-find-the-upgrade-code-productcode-of-an-installed-application-in-win-7)
- [How can I find the upgrade code for an installed application in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936064/how-can-i-find-the-upgrade-code-for-an-installed-application-in-c)
- [Wix: how to uninstall previously installed application that is installed using different installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326657/wix-how-to-uninstall-previously-installed-application-that-is-installed-using-d/24340339#24340339)
- [WiX - Doing a major upgrade on a multi instance install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860622/wix-doing-a-major-upgrade-on-a-multi-instance-install/22862283#22862283)
- [how to find out which products are installed - newer product are already installed MSI windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963089/how-to-find-out-which-products-are-installed-newer-product-are-already-install/28971679#28971679) (using VBScript)
- [How to uninstall with msiexec using product id guid without .msi file present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491631/how-to-uninstall-with-msiexec-using-product-id-guid-without-msi-file-present/21502621#21502621)
- [Find GUID of MSI Package](https://serverfault.com/questions/165126/find-guid-of-msi-package/274673#274673)

Comment: Thank you. I tried using geek.exe and Revo but I nuked by registry for a keyword but I didn't record the guid and this would showed me the blank ones.

Comment: `Win32_Product` should really not be queried, as it is not a read-only operation. Apparently it runs a consistency check on every package and then proceeds with repair installations if any are found. See https://sdmsoftware.com/group-policy-blog/wmi/why-win32_product-is-bad-news/ and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974524

Comment: I believe this is thoroughly documented in the answer above already (disclaimer sections). ``Win32_Product`` is only called because the UpgradeCode is not easily accessible in other ways. [**There is another way described here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48615123/129130), but it also has some unpleasant aspects (MSI API session objects).

Comment: I thought you were talking about UpgradeCode. You can get the ProductCode easily via MSI API, which I provide a VBScript for above (section 3 in "Alternative Tools"). Maybe a Powershell cmdlet could be created to do the job. Maybe I will have a look when I get the time. It could go via MSI API directly - under the hood.

Comment: How can we sort the "table formatted" output in `get-wmiobject Win32_Product...` by name (to get the same list as on 'Programs and Features')?

Comment: I have a much more advanced VBScript to format the output in a sortable, and filterable / searchable HTML format, but I am not done with its QA and it is also primarily for my own use and testing. It also shows upgrade codes and related product codes (sharing the same upgrade code). I would suggest you open the exported text file in a spreadsheet application (such as Microsoft Excel), and import it as a delimited list with comma as separator - then you can do whatever you want with for formatting. Just rename the output file to msiinfo.csv and double click it - then set comma as delimiter.

Comment: Very good overview of MSI package internals. I'm finding some issues of using the commands in scripting since the powershell itself or `Format-Table` are cutting away the results depending on the powershell buffer size when used interactively, and in scripting it's behaving similarly making the output useless.

Comment: Maybe try maximizing the window or piping the content? I am not really up to speed on PowerShell. Not properly potty-trained, but you can try to first maximize the Powershell window and then run again - this usually works if your screen estate is large enough. You can also try to output to a file without the `-autosize` option: `get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table IdentifyingNumber, Name, LocalPackage | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\User\Desktop\MSI-Packages.txt`

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough Rep points to reply to Stein Asmul directly, maybe someone can message him, but here is a powershell one-liner I adapted from the VBScript solution which I found to be more reliable than the existing powershell one-liner, particularly when running as a non-admin, and it's much faster

```ps
$Installer = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer; $InstallerProducts = $Installer.ProductsEx("", "", 7); $InstalledProducts = ForEach($Product in $InstallerProducts){[PSCustomObject]@{ProductCode = $Product.ProductCode(); LocalPackage = $Product.InstallProperty("LocalPackage"); VersionString = $Product.InstallProperty("VersionString"); ProductPath = $Product.InstallProperty("ProductName")}} $InstalledProducts
```

Pro-tip: Change the 7 to a 3 to find programs lurking as per-user installs rather than machine wide.

Comment: Yes, this goes via COM rarther than WMI and is hence as fast as the VBScript option that I list. I will incorporate this as a comment to the first point.

Answer (score 2):

If you have too many installers to find what you are looking for easily, here is some powershell to provide a filter and narrow it down a little by display name.

```
$filter = "*core*sdk*"; (Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall).Name | % { $path = "Registry::$_"; Get-ItemProperty $path } | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like $filter } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, PsChildName
```

Comment: As for previous answers, Get-WmiObject is not available in PS 7. This code works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: There's also `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` if the native registry hive doesn't have it

Answer (score 0):

There is also a very helpful GUI tool called Product Browser which appears to be made by Microsoft or at least an employee of Microsoft.

It can be found on Github here [Product Browser](https://github.com/suyouquan/SQLSetupTools)

I personally had a very easy time locating the GUID I needed with this.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [MSI Finder](https://github.com/yariker/MsiFinder). It lets you search for products or components by name, GUID or location, view their properties, as well as repair or uninstall individual products.

Disclaimer: I was looking for a similar solution, but couldn't find anything reliable or easy to use. So, I developed this tool.