# PowerShell: Get the MSI product code out of a MSI file without installing?

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

Is there a possibility to retreive the MSI product code out of a MSI file without installing it with PowerShell? I want to compare the product code of a MSI file with the MSI codes installed on a maschine to find out if the file was installed in the past.

Comment: [List of free tools you can used to view MSI files down the page here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files) (Orca, SuperOrca, etc...). The ProductCode can be found in the **`Property table`** once you have a tool capable of reading MSI files. And you can [find the product code for installed MSI setups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29937568/129130).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a script that reads the product code based on [this article][1]:

```
$path = "pathto.msi"

$comObjWI = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
$MSIDatabase = $comObjWI.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenDatabase","InvokeMethod",$Null,$comObjWI,@($Path,0))
$Query = "SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductCode'"
$View = $MSIDatabase.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenView","InvokeMethod",$null,$MSIDatabase,($Query))
$View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $null, $View, $null)
$Record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Fetch","InvokeMethod",$null,$View,$null)
$Value = $Record.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData","GetProperty",$null,$Record,1)
```

`$Value` now contains the product code.
[1]: http://www.scconfigmgr.com/2014/08/22/how-to-get-msi-file-information-with-powershell/

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, you need the whole script code from the article, the extract is not working like this. But thanks! This solved the problem!

Comment: Replace "$WindowsInstaller" with "$comObjWI" and the extract will work

Comment: I think you need to remove the space between `$comObjWI` and `.getType()` on the 3rd line of code

Answer (score 7):

A shorter way to get the ProductCode from a MSI package:

```
Get-AppLockerFileInformation -Path "C:\PathTo\my.msi" | select -ExpandProperty Publisher | Select BinaryName
```

Comment: binaryname is empty when I try this

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that it does not work if your MSI is not digitally signed.

Answer (score 0):

If the product is NOT installed on the computer, you can try to uninstall it anyway and write to a log with the flag /lv. This should record the Product Code in the log.

```
msiexec /x c:\temp\myproduct.msi /lv mymsi.log
select-string "ProductCode" -path mymsi.log
```