# InstallShield error: "Failed to launch proxy process"

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2015

I am trying to build an installer using InstallShield 2015 and during installation it spits out an error like this in the GUI:

```
The wizard was interrupted before ProductNameGoesHere was installed.
```

The only problematic line I see in the logs is this:

```
1-9-2018[11:15:33 PM]: Failed to launch proxy process 'C:\Users\rsheink\AppData\Local\Temp\{21683818-C622-4EE7-B2D1-A407FE37E1E4}\setup64.exe', error 2
```

Can somebody please help Me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This line is interesting in the log: "*UI DLL: Display Error: The installation of TenLira appears to have failed. Do you want to continue the installation?*"

You seem to be running the command line `EXE parcel command line: /s /x /v"/qn"`. So this appears to be an uninstall. Did you try this command line manually? It seems the `/x` and  the `/v"/qn"` are redundant - both indicating uninstall. The first is a setup.exe-specific command, whereas the latter is passed to `msiexec.exe`. I would try with one or the other. I would prefer to keep `/v"/qn"` and remove `/x` as my first test.

**Or could you just uninstall by product code instead?** That should be more reliable, and you could potentially eliminate the whole setup.exe from your bundle? (the cached MSI in `%SystemRoot%\Installer` should be enough - especially important if the setup.exe is very big). Also try without hard coded logging in the msiexec.exe command if there are problems (perhaps the suite project does its own logging).

`msiexec.exe /x {YOUR-PRODUCT-GUID-HERE} /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log"`

Quick Parameter Explanation:

```
/X = run uninstall sequence
/QN = run completely silently
/L*V "C:\msilog.log"= verbose logging at path specified
{YOUR-PRODUCT-GUID-HERE} = product guid of app to uninstall.
```

Some links for reference:

- **[Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)**.
- **[How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569#29937569)**

---

Here is the first answer before the nature of the problem was better understood. I will leave it in:

[**This looks quite similar**](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?202119-Suite-install-64-bit-suite-folder-properties-report-32-bit-paths&p=479568#post479568) (answer from DebbieL), but it is for Installshield 2012. Could you try the workaround she proposes?

Remote content replicated here in case the link breaks:

- find the SetupSuite64.exe file that's installed the following location:
  `InstallShield Program Files Folder\Redist\Language Independent\x64`
- Make a copy of it and rename it to this: `Setup64.exe`
- Include that Setup64.exe file in your Suite project as a support file, and rebuild the Suite.
- Once you do that, the Suite should be able to handle ProgramFiles64Folder as expected.

As stated, this is just a summary from the linked answer by DebbieL. Please peruse the entire thread / answer (there are 3 pages worth of questions and answers).

Let us know how this works out for you, and if it doesn't work I will try to "evolve" this answer.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your answer! I did indeed found the link You mention in Google - I understand its a bug in IS2012 (I use IS2015) - but I tried the suggested solution any way. The GUI of the installer still shows the same error string but the log is now different: the original error is no longer there, but a new error now presents it self. Here is is: `Transaction: parcel returned error status 80004004`. Here is the full log file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbjgihsqd1dipts/New%20Text%20Document.txt?dl=0.

Comment: I added a new thing you can try, perhaps this is just a broken uninstall command?

Comment: Thank You very much for Your help. Eventually, We purchased their support and they solved the problem (they connected remotely and did some voodoo).