# Is there any way to find out software versions through Cygwin command line

Tags: cygwin, registry, version

I'm testing different version of a Windows software, the version of this software doesn't seem to be kept in the registry. I'm trying to find a CLI tool or a command to get the version of any software on Windows.

I tried looking at the registry but the version doesn't seem to be there. Therefore `reg query` command won't help me. I've performed Google searches to find out if anybody already tried that or built a tool for this but... no luck so I ended here.

The returned output can be anything... as long as the version is written. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you specify what all applications you are trying to track for versions? Every application has a variety of ways of reporting their versions, you would need to look at their official documentations to get version information.

Answer (score -1):

I found this eventually [How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup) - thats pretty much what I needed. It is going to be a little bit more complicated then I thought. I have to find the product GUID before querying the registry in my case.

I want to achieve this when using a bash terminal. If anybody already found a solution, I would be curious to know what was it.