# Visual Studio setup project and msm file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, setup-project, merge-module

I need to create a Setup Project using Visual Studio. This project contains a .msm file and no Others files.

When I create the .msi file correctly it creates an empty folder in Application Folder and all my software work properly.

There is a way to create a Setup Project without the Application Folder considering that it is an empy folder?

Thank you.[image]

Comment: When opening your MSI with Orca, what does the Directory table look like? Screenshot? [How to get Orca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29937569/129130) (description in text).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I have edited my question with the screenshot

Comment: It might be the merge module itself which adds this folder. You could try to point the default folder for your whole MSI to a system folder perhaps, but I would just leave it.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and checkout: https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials