# Checking if an MSI package is installed on Windows

Tags: ansible, windows-installer

I am creating a playbook that will install an MSI package on a Windows server, but the `win_package` module does not respond if the MSI package is already installed. The Ansible documentation says that I can use `product_id` of an MSI package while installing the package, but the `product_id` only works if the previously installed package version is the same version as the package I am installing - the Windows server might have a different version of same installer.

How can I uninstall the previous version, and install the current version, using Ansible?

Answer (score 0):

***Major Upgrade***: A properly authored MSI will uninstall previous versions before it installs the newest by means of a ["major upgrade"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/major-upgrades) implemented via the [Upgrade table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/upgrade-table) inside the MSI.

***Tool***: How to implement a major upgrade depends on the tool you use ([Installshield, Advanced Installer, WiX, etc...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840)). The link above is from the MSI SDK (in first paragraph above). It shows the real "under the hood - MSI way to do it". In other words the technology itself with no special features from vendor tools to help you make things easy.

***Uninstall***: The easiest way to manually uninstall an existing MSI is by using an msiexec.exe command line:

```
msiexec.exe /x {11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111X}
```

Details on how to find existing installations and how to uninstall here:

- ***Find Installed MSIs***: [How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569#29937569)
- ***Uninstall an MSI***: [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)