# I met the problem " A later version is already installed." when installing windows sdk for uwp managed apps

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, windows-installer

I met the problem ***“ A later version is already installed”*** when installing windows sdk for uwp managed apps. I found a lot of information, but my network is ok and windows updater is also ok, but I haven't found about *'A later version is already installed'*.

The whole log is here:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 5/25/2021  20:32:12  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\{1A75E199-3589-42B1-A5E0-E6CE672EDA12}\.be\winsdksetup.exe ===
MSI (c) (00:64) [20:32:12:363]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (00:64) [20:32:12:363]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (00:64) [20:32:12:363]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}v10.1.0.0\Redistributable\10.1.0.0\UAPSDKAddOn-x86.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (00:64) [20:32:12:363]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (00:64) [20:32:12:363]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (00:64) [20:32:12:366]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (00:64) [20:32:12:366]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (00:64) [20:32:12:366]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (48:B0) [20:32:12:368]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}v10.1.0.0\Redistributable\10.1.0.0\UAPSDKAddOn-x86.msi
MSI (s) (48:B0) [20:32:12:368]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:369]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:369]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:369]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}v10.1.0.0\Redistributable\10.1.0.0\UAPSDKAddOn-x86.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:369]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:390]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:390]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:392]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:394]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}v10.1.0.0\Redistributable\10.1.0.0\UAPSDKAddOn-x86.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:394]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}v10.1.0.0\Redistributable\10.1.0.0\UAPSDKAddOn-x86.msi has a digital signature
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:399]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}v10.1.0.0\Redistributable\10.1.0.0\UAPSDKAddOn-x86.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:399]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:401]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:401]: Original package ==> C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}v10.1.0.0\Redistributable\10.1.0.0\UAPSDKAddOn-x86.msi
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:401]: Package we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\2a31e.msi
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:402]: APPCOMPAT: Compatibility mode property overrides found.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:402]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:402]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:406]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:406]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:406]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiFileHash 
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:406]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:406]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:406]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:406]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: Transforms are not secure.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Control 
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\windowssdk\Windows_Software_Development_Kit___Windows_10.0.19041.685_20210525202933_041_package_Facade_winmd.log'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: Command Line: MSIFASTINSTALL=7 EXTUI=1 REBOOT=ReallySuppress CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Users\admin\Downloads CLIENTUILEVEL=3 MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI=1 CLIENTPROCESSID=11008 
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{2494658B-1635-4C4A-85AA-E31A4480A3FA}'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           ''
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}'
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}'
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: Product {E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340} is not managed.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: MSI_LUA: Credential prompt not required, user is an admin
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: Package name extracted from package path: 'UAPSDKAddOn-x86.msi'
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:407]: Package to be registered: 'UAPSDKAddOn-x86.msi'
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: Product installation will be elevated because user is admin and product is being installed per-machine.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: Running product '{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MSIFASTINSTALL property. Its value is '7'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXTUI property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding REBOOT property. Its value is 'ReallySuppress'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\Users\admin\Downloads'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '3'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '11008'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: Machine policy value 'DisableAutomaticApplicationShutdown' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRestartManagerSessionKey property. Its value is '406ab11bc8ce9b46a783ece5b4142bef'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: RESTART MANAGER: Session opened.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:411]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '300'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:412]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:413]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\Favorites
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:413]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:414]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\Documents
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:415]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:415]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:416]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:417]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:417]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:418]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:418]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\Pictures
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:420]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:420]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:421]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:422]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:422]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Public\Desktop
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:423]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:423]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:424]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\admin\Desktop
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Windows\Fonts
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: MSI_LUA: Setting MsiRunningElevated property to 1 because the install is already running elevated.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRunningElevated property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'admin'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\Windows\Installer\2a31e.msi'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}v10.1.0.0\Redistributable\10.1.0.0\UAPSDKAddOn-x86.msi'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: EEUI - Disabling MsiEmbeddedUI due to existing external or embedded UI
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: EEUI - Disabling MsiEmbeddedUI for service because it's not a quiet/basic install
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage 
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '2'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiUISourceResOnly property. Its value is '1'.
=== Logging started: 5/25/2021  20:32:12 ===
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: APPCOMPAT: [DetectVersionLaunchCondition] Launch condition already passes.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Doing action: INSTALL
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 20:32:12: INSTALL.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Running ExecuteSequence
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 20:32:12: FindRelatedProducts.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding NEWERVERSIONDETECTED property. Its value is '{E6F877A1-2F65-4BF0-87B6-A4071B7663D3}'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Doing action: AppSearch
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 20:32:12: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 20:32:12: AppSearch.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WINDOWS10KITSROOT property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\'.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Doing action: LaunchConditions
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 20:32:12: AppSearch. Return value 1.
Action start 20:32:12: LaunchConditions.
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:426]: Product: Windows SDK AddOn -- A later version is already installed.

A later version is already installed.
Action ended 20:32:12: LaunchConditions. Return value 3.
Action ended 20:32:12: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {8061F133-4FE2-42AC-8145-03F3F866CF69}
Property(S): WINDOWS10KITSROOT = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): Manufacturer = Microsoft Corporation
Property(S): ProductCode = {E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): ProductName = Windows SDK AddOn
Property(S): ProductVersion = 10.1.0.0
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = IGNOREDEPENDENCIES;NEWERVERSIONDETECTED;OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED
Property(S): NEWERVERSIONDETECTED = {E6F877A1-2F65-4BF0-87B6-A4071B7663D3}
Property(S): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\windowssdk\Windows_Software_Development_Kit___Windows_10.0.19041.685_20210525202933_041_package_Facade_winmd.log
Property(S): PackageCode = {2494658B-1635-4C4A-85AA-E31A4480A3FA}
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): MSIFASTINSTALL = 7
Property(S): EXTUI = 1
Property(S): REBOOT = ReallySuppress
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Users\admin\Downloads
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 3
Property(S): MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI = 1
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 11008
Property(S): MsiRestartManagerSessionKey = 406ab11bc8ce9b46a783ece5b4142bef
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 300
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(S): VersionNT = 603
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\
Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(S): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\admin\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\admin\Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\admin\Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(S): Msix64 = 6
Property(S): Intel = 6
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 8092
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 9499
Property(S): AdminUser = 1
Property(S): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
Property(S): LogonUser = admin
Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-21-3750901376-3460145651-420115384-1001
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ComputerName = DESKTOP-JI7GM19
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 2052
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 19
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 20:32:12
Property(S): Date = 2021/5/25
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.8.4084.0
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.19041.546
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): USERNAME = admin
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\Windows\Installer\2a31e.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E18618EC-D9DB-4BCE-B382-85ADA2CBB340}v10.1.0.0\Redistributable\10.1.0.0\UAPSDKAddOn-x86.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 2
Property(S): MsiUISourceResOnly = 1
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:441]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:441]: Product: Windows SDK AddOn -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:441]: Windows Installer 已安装产品。产品名称: Windows SDK AddOn。产品版本: 10.1.0.0。产品语言: 1033。制造商: Microsoft Corporation。安装成功或错误状态: 1603。

MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:441]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (48:60) [20:32:12:441]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (48:B0) [20:32:12:441]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (48:B0) [20:32:12:441]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
=== Logging stopped: 5/25/2021  20:32:12 ===
MSI (s) (48:B0) [20:32:12:441]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (48:B0) [20:32:12:441]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (48:B0) [20:32:12:441]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (48:B0) [20:32:12:441]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (48:B0) [20:32:12:441]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (48:B0) [20:32:12:441]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (00:64) [20:32:12:441]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (00:64) [20:32:12:441]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 5/25/2021  20:32:12 ===
```

Answer (score 1):

***Existing Install***: For an MSI file this usually means that there is a version of the same MSI installed which shares the same product code. It looks like this is an MSI based on the log file you provide (there can also be other mechanisms at work).

***Suggestion***: It looks like you have a newer version installed with product code:
**`{E6F877A1-2F65-4BF0-87B6-A4071B7663D3}`**, but I have not tested this and can not guarantee it. You can uninstall this version using (at your own risk):

```
msiexec /x {E6F877A1-2F65-4BF0-87B6-A4071B7663D3}
```

***Installed Product List***: You can [get a list of installed products and their product codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29937569/129130). You will find some scripts linked there in section 2 - try them to get a list of installed products. Then you can uninstall the one blocking the install of your new setup with: **`msiexec /x [ProductCode]`**