# How to configure StartMenu location/path within MSI using MS Orca?

Tags: deployment, server, windows-installer, admin, gpo

I am deploying Mozilla Thunderbird using a provided MSI file. I would like to cange the default StartMenu path from:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Thunderbird\
```

to

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Communication Tools\
```

I am no pro in using Orca to edit MSI files, though I know it is possible to make the necessary adjustments. The problem I am seeing here is lacking documentation and a clear path on what elements of the MSI properties need to be changed.

Is there any way to change the path for the Start Menu entry?

The MSI can be found here:
https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/all/

Comment: It looks like that is just an MSI wrapper and not a proper MSI file. The real installer is in the Binary table of the MSI. You can extract it using Orca. It seems to be some sort of proprietary format. You can probably extract it and capture it in MSI format yourself - this is what most large corporations do for unconventional installers. Not all installers are possible to capture (for example when they create unique files or keys based on local computer configuration and that kind of thing).

Comment: Thank you Stein Asmul. I will look into the extraction of the MSI in the next months. Currently, I solved the issue by importing the MSI to Advanced Installer and configuring the folders and files to be installed as wished and regenerated a new MSI. This solved the issue for the moment, although a better fix can be done once the MSI is extracted. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe I have a different MSI. In my version I have to use Orca - the Microsoft MSI viewer tool ([how to find the Orca tool - mid page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29937569/129130)), and then I go to the Binary table once I have opened the MSI and double click the Binary Data cell. Then I write to disk the content as Setup.exe and run that to see what happens (Select "Write binary to filename" and press OK - and give it the name setup.exe). It looks like this Setup.exe might be a proprietary setup format from the vendor?