# How to migrate from InstallShield to Visual Studio Installer Projects

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, installshield

I have an application in VS 2015, and I am using *Visual Studio Installer Projects* to generate the installer. On each new version, I change the **Version** and the **ProductCode**, while the **UpgradeCode** remains the same, so that the installer replaces the old versions of the application previously installed in the machine. This works just right, nothing wrong here.

BUT, There are older versions of this application running on some of the clients' machines, and I know that the installer of those versions was made using *InstallShield*. The problem is that I can't make the new installer to replace those old versions, although I'm using the same UpgradeCode and the same Name... It just installs the new version but the old one remains on the machine.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It might be worth you including the ProductCode, ProductVersion, PackageCode and UpgradeCode of all MSIs in your question. Also, state the values in your Upgrade table...

Comment: What is the PackageCode? I can't find it on Visual Studio Installer Projects

Comment: It's in the Summary Information Stream.  I'm not sure you can do it natively in VS (not that I've tried) - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49086bd5-7f58-48ad-b9e5-c16c549b22db/how-to-update-quotpackage-codequot-in-msi-file-?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: You might want to use Orca (for simplicity) to get the functionality working, and then try and implement the changes via VS.  You might ultimately need to use WiX, not sure...

Comment: You should create a list of the installed applications on machine with those installshield versions present. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569#29937569). I would recommend you [run this script](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/MsiHtmlReport-Mini-V4.vbs). It will create a html table of the installed products. It takes a while to run. Then you can see if the upgrade codes are really the same, and what the other codes and details are for the products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with this exact issue for a while when replacing an InstallShield project with a VS Installer project. The `UpgradeCode` was identical between the two & `RemovePreviousVersions` was `True`..

The thing that got me was the `InstallAllUsers` property. These need to be the same for both installer projects. If InstallShield was installed for all users, VS Installer cannot overwrite it if it only installs for the current user.

Comment: Thank you @David ! Your answer has solved my problem. I had everything under control: version number, product code, upgrade code, assambly code... But THAT was missing. I set InstallAllUsers to True, and now it works. The new installer replaces the old installshield-generated versions correctly.